# Does swift have the equivalent of a "with block"

Tags: swift

In several Microsoft languages, there is the idea of a "with block".  For example, instead of

```
myObject.x = 5
myObject.y = 10
myObject.z = 12
```

you can write something like

```
With myObject
    .x = 5
    .y = 10
    .z = 12
End With
```

Is there something similar in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built into the language, but there is a library called [Then](https://github.com/devxoul/Then) which provides this functionality:

```
let myObject = MyObject().then {
    $0.x = 5
    $0.y = 10
    $0.z = 12
}
```

If you want this behavior on instantiation without a dependency, you can use a var that is returned from a closure:

```
let myObject: MyObject = {
    let _myObject = MyObject()
    _myObject.x = 5
    _myObject.y = 10
    _myObject.z = 12
    return _myObject
}()
```

Comment: Very interesting... Thank you!